# Save coordinates as polygon type in Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have the coordinates of polygon in JSON object and I want to save them as polygon type in database. This is my code-

```
$Coordinates   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Coordinates']);

"INSERT into table_name (polygon) VALUES(PolyFromText('POLYGON('" .($Coordinates). "')'))";
```

where $coordinates are the stringified Lat and Long of the polygon vertices.

For ex.- Coordinates=

"[[36.37485644939407,-96.68243408203125],[35.94465937365276,-96.998291015625],[36.117908916563685,-96.10015869140625]]"

and these are generating from this code-

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(polygon) {
var coordinates_poly = polygon.overlay.getPath().getArray();

    var lat_poly = [];
    var lng_poly = [];
    var Coordinates = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <coordinates_poly.length; i++){
    lat_poly = coordinates_poly[i].lat();
    lng_poly = coordinates_poly[i].lng();
    Data = [lat_poly,lng_poly];
    Coordinates.push(Data);
    }
    var JSON_Coordinates = JSON.stringify(Coordinates);
    document.getElementById("coordinates").value= '"'+JSON_Coordinates+'"';
```

but the error is-

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '\"[[36.37485644939407,-96.68243408203125],[35.94465937365276,-96.998291015625],[' at line 1

Please someone help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: "INSERT into polygon VALUES ('$Coordinates')";

Answer (score 1):

Use correct syntax. For example:

```
POLYGON((50.866753 5.686455, 50.859819 5.708942, 50.851475 5.722675, 50.841611 5.720615, 50.834023 5.708427, 50.840744 5.689373, 50.858735 5.673923, 50.866753 5.686455))
```

See here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-polygon-property-functions.html

Comment: I have already seen that. There they are taking coordinates manually, in my case the coordinates are being taken from google map polygon drawing tool, and it takes starting and ending point coordinates only once.

Comment: Why cant you preprocess this array to correct sql format?

Comment: please enlighten me how to do that.